# Help with sending data to MIT app inventor through bluetooth

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

[image: MIT Code to receive and display bluetooth data]
I'm trying to connect my arduino bluetooth sensor to an MIT App Inventor app I made, and in doing so display the readings of two of my sensors. Whenever I test the sensors in the serial monitor, I get normal readings, but sending them to MIT APP Inventor makes them glitch out and give me the error "Select list item: Attempt to get item number 2 of a list of length 1". I've reviewed all of my code for both the Arduino and the MIT App Inventor, and I haven't been able to find anything that may be hindering me. The timer interval for the MIT App inventor code is correct.

My Arduino code is below; the MIT app inventor code is shown in the above image

```
#define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS true    // Set-up low-level interrupts for most acurate BPM math.
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>     // Includes the PulseSensorPlayground Library.   

//  Variables
const int PulseWire = A1;       // PulseSensor PURPLE WIRE connected to ANALOG PIN A1
int Threshold = 550;           // Determine which Signal to "count as a beat" and which to ignore.
                               // Use the "Gettting Started Project" to fine-tune Threshold Value beyond default setting.
                               // Otherwise leave the default "550" value. 
const int PIEZO_PIN = A0; // Piezo output

PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;  // Creates an instance of the PulseSensorPlayground object called "pulseSensor"


void setup() {   
  Serial.begin(9600);          // For Serial Monitor
  // Configure the PulseSensor object, by assigning our variables to it. 
  pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseWire);   
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(Threshold);   
  }
void loop() {
  int piezoADC = analogRead(PIEZO_PIN); //Get the analog value of the Piezo sensor
  float piezoV = (piezoADC / 1023.0 * 5.0);  //Get the voltage of the Piezo sensor
  int myBPM = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute(); //Get the BPM detected of the user

  Serial.print((double)piezoV); // Print Piezo voltage

  Serial.print("|"); //Use this character to separate the vibration from the heartbeat

  if (pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute() == 0){
  Serial.println("N/A"); 
 }
 else{
  Serial.println((int)myBPM); //Print the BPM
 } 
  delay(5000);

}
```

Comment: the split text at `"|"` ... is that `"|"` or `" | "`?

Comment: The split text is |, not an capital i or a lowercase L. The thing where you click shift and the backslash key.

Comment: start by writing a minimal sketch that sends a single fixed byte every 5 seconds or so. ..... write an app to receive that byte

Comment: I'm not asking if it's `"l"` or `"I"` or `"1"` - I'm asking if it's `"|"` or `" | "` .... the difference being **SPACES**

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. No spaces, its just "|"

Comment: My guess is that `BytesAvailableToReceive > 0` is true after `Serial.print((double)piezoV)` but before `Serial.print("|")` ... hence the issue ... try changing your input processing to only process input once it receives end-of-line ... i.e. `\n` .... alternatively `Serial.printf("%f|%s\n", (double)piezoV, myBPM ? "N/A" : String(myBPM));` may work for you

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a bit new to Arduino and I don't quite understand how I would change the example code you gave me to put it into my sketch. I understand the issue you're pointing out, though. Could you please rephrase the code somewhat? Again, I'm sorry and I hope this won't annoy you too much.

EDIT: It's because whenever I paste your code into my sketch, it gives me the error "HardwareSerial has no member named printf", despite working with different inputs.

Comment: Scratch that, printf never works.

Comment: To clarify on what I meant by the first comment: putting the example code you gave me into the sketch causes a lot of errors, so I was wondering if you could please reformat it so it would work with the code without any issues?

Comment: oh ... I'm spoiled by having `printf` on ESP8266 Arduino :p - if you can't print using `printf` then use `char buffer[80]; sprintf(buffer, "%f|%s\n", (double)piezoV, myBPM ? "N/A" : String(myBPM)); Serial.print(buffer);` perhaps

Comment: The error still occurs; perhaps I need to place it in a specific place in the code, or do I maybe have to replace something?

Comment: Yeah, I'd say the only fix is to make sure the receiving side doesn't "parse" the received data until it gets all of it

Comment: How would I do such a thing? I tried editing the MIT App Inventor so that it would only display the data if the length of the list was 2 (the amount of individual readings I should get), but instead the app now *never* shows the data, almost like it's not receiving readings at all.

Comment: Another thing: I think I might be able to use the solution you gave me, I just need to know where I should place that line of code and what I should replace with it.